# Listening to events on Web Components in HTML

Tags: web-component, custom-events

I've looked all over for this, can find lots of examples listening to custom events programatically with JS, but nothing declaratively in HTML.

I've got a web component where I dispatch an event from inside.

If I attach a listener with JS, the handler fires, if I attach the listener in the HTML, it never fires. Is this possible?

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("myWebComp").addEventListener("myevent", progListener);

    function progListener(event) { 
        //This will fire
        console.log("progListener")
    }

    function declListener(event) { 
        //This will NOT fire
        console.log("declListener")
    }

</script>

<body>
    <my=web-comp id="myWebComp" myevent="declListener(event)" onmyevent="declListener(event)></my-web-comp>
</body>`
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comment on the now deleted answer:

> *a web component still don't act like a proper element*

Web Components ***are*** proper elements, extended from HTMLElement

And you can not set **Custom** Event `on*` *declarative* Event Handlers on a `DIV` either
(unless you use build-step tooling that transpiles your code)

So all `on*` *declarative* Event handlers can be set on a Web Component:

- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-handlers-on-elements,-document-objects,-and-window-objects

If you want a custom handler, you use `addEventListener`

Comment: Still a poor imitation in my eyes. I wouldn't expect to me able to do that with other components (i.e. a div), that stuff should be sandboxed, but I would expect to be able to do the same with the ones I build, as the elements that are available out the box, to consider them proper. We were able to do this stuff so long ago with MXML and AS, but it still seems a way off in HTML and JS. It is what it is. Don't know why the original answer was deleted, as it answered my question perfectly.

Comment: We used metadata to expose events to markup [Event(name="change", type="package.events.CustomEvent")]

Comment: And if that had to to the Web, you had a build step to "decode" your Markup to valid HTML. Yes, the Web sucks, and if you don't like its language, then don't use it. Try Rust